# why 3 areas to configure jdk in IntellijIDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, configuration

After having spent 2 days on IntellijIDEA, i am totaly lost regarding the ways to configure jdks. why some many menu/places to do it ?

In fact, we have :

```
 File | Project Structure | SDK 

 File | settings | Build Tools Maven | Runner | JRE 

 Run | Profile | edit configurations.. | Build and run
```

What is the usage of each one ?
it is so complicated !

thanks.

Comment: The first one is the JDK that is used to compile your project. The last one is the one used to run your application. It makes sense to separate those two so you can test how your application runs on different JDKs if you plan to support older JDKs (e.g. project JDK is Java 11 and you need to test on all Java version from 11 to 20). I do not know about the second one, but "Build Tools Maven" -> "Runner" -> "JRE" seems like a strong hint as to its usage.

Comment: Maven is a Java application. The second one defines the JRE that is used to run the Maven application.

Comment: ok thanks @ThomasBehr but to be precise, the "edit configurations.." is not labeled for "run" application but for "build and run" the application. So why to compile with the "project structure" jdk if there is too a "build" jdk ? it is not clear for me.

Comment: It is labeled "Build and run" in "Edit Configurations", because you can specify if your application should be rebuild before each run - i.e. you can specify some settings that are not "run" settings there as well. Nevertheless, the JRE in "Build and run" is for running the application not for compiling the application. (The application is always compiled with the "Project Structure" -> "SDK" JDK. This is why it is possible to specify a JRE in "Build and run". If that value was used for compiling, it would have to be a JDK, because the javac compiler is not part of a JRE.)

Comment: In any case, if the settings are not clear to you, just specify the "Project Structure" -> "SDK" and leave the rest as is. The "Build and run" JRE will default to the JRE from the "Project Structure" -> "SDK". This should work fine unless your "Project Structure" -> "SDK" is something very old like Java 1.4 (which is really uncommon nowadays and requires additional IDEA setup to work anyways).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File | Project Structure | SDK (and Language Level)` defines which libraries and methods you will have access to when writing the code.
[Learn more](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-settings-and-structure.html#project-sdk)

`File | settings | Build Tools Maven | Runner | JRE` is for Maven only (not all Projects use Maven).
Maven is a stand-alone tool bundled with Intellij IDEA, that can build (put together) your Project for you and, optionally, run tests against it, to make sure the application works as intended.
For most cases it's fine to use the same JDK as in `File | Project Structure | SDK` here.
[Learn more](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_runner_jdk)

`Run | Profile | Edit Configurations... | Build and Run` defines which JDK will be used for your application when you run it (at runtime).
Usually it's best to keep it the same as `File | Project Structure | SDK`
[Learn more](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html)

You can easily keep all those settings at their defaults, but, if needed, IDEA gives you an option to write, build and run your application with any combination of JDKs you may need.
This often can be the case for enterprise and legacy applications.